# DataTable not Found error

Tags: c#, textbox, dataset

After doing more reading and research into managing data, I have redone the code based off the MSDN site for a dataset; however, I am running into a snag.  I believe I have declared the dataset within a class-level; however, whenever I attempt to pull that dataset with

```
DataRow[] drRow = tblEmployee.Select("EmployeeKey = " + TextBox12.Text)
```

I am getting the errors:

> 1. The name 'tblEmployees' does not exist in the current context
> 2. The name 'TextBox12' does not exist in the current context

I want to be able to declare it at the class level so I can call it from anywhere within the form.

I have already read through the MSDN site on class levels, and honestly I think that has just confused me to a greater degree.

Basically is what I want to happen is dataset provides a list of employees in alphabitical order by first name, then when a user selects the the employee from drop down box, it should select the employee ID and display it in textBox12, then perform a search of the tblEmplpoyees for the remaining data to display for the employee such as fields defined in //comments in the code.

Can someone assist me with this, here is what I have for code atm:

```
namespace Tempus.Menus
{
public partial class Employees : Form
{
    public class myData
    {
        DataSet[]drRow = tblEmployees.Select("EmployeeKey = " + TextBox12.Text);;
    }
    public Employees()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Connect to database for Employees Table Headers
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=server\CHCTEMPUS;Integrated Security=true;" +
            "user id=userID;password=password;" +
            "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
            "Database=Database;" +
            "connection timeout=30");

        SqlDataAdapter daEmployees
            = new SqlDataAdapter("Select *, Lname +', '+ Fname as LastFirst, Fname +' '+ Lname as FirstLast FROM Employees WHERE Lname IS NOT NULL AND Fname IS NOT NULL", myConnection);



        DataSet dsEmployees = new DataSet("Employees");
        daEmployees.FillSchema(dsEmployees, SchemaType.Source, "Employees");
        daEmployees.Fill(dsEmployees, "Employees");

        DataTable tblEmployees;
        tblEmployees = dsEmployees.Tables["Employees"];



        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstLast";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "employeeNumber";
        comboBox1.DataSource = tblEmployees;



        try
        { }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConnection != null)
            {
                myConnection.Dispose();
            }


        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

        comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;

    }



  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        {
            textBox12.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {

            textBox1.Text = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }



    private void Employees_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Last Name

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //First Name
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Middle Name
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Hire Date
    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Term Date
    }

    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Company
    }

    private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Notes
    }

    private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //PTO
    }

    private void textBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //SNP
    }

    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Credentials
    }

    private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Employee Full Name (First Last)

    }

    private void textBox12_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Employee ID
    }

    private void textBox13_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Branch

    }
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)

                {

            // logic here for if the box has now been checked


                }

            else

                {

                // what to do if the box has been unchecked


                }

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main myNewForm = new Main();

        myNewForm.Show();

        this.Close();
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reports myNewForm = new Reports();

        myNewForm.Show();

        this.Close();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: And can you paste the code where this is used?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I had selected all from Namespace down.  My Apologies.

Comment: show us more code, especially the context in which the call is made and the error is thrown

Comment: @ChrisTurner - I still don't see the code where you say the error is.

Comment: @Preet Sangha - Error is being raised on line 18 column 30; however, on here it is in public class myData near the top of the code

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a local variable in the constructor of `Employees`:

```
DataTable tblEmployees;
tblEmployees = dsEmployees.Tables["Employees"];
```

Now you're trying to access that local variable from wirthin another class:

```
public class myData
{
    DataSet[]drRow = tblEmployees.Select("EmployeeKey = " + TextBox12.Text);;
}
```

Of course that does not work. For the same reason you don't have access to the instance of `TextBox12` in the form.

I assume that you actually want to filter the `DataTable` by the entered text. 
You should handle an event, for example a (filter-)button-click event.

Then  you could use LNQ-To-DataSet which is more readable and maintanable to filter the rows. You could declare the table for example as member variable in the form and initialize it in [form_load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx):

```
private DataTable tblEmployees;

private void buttonFilter_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(tblEmployees != null)
   {
       DataTable filtered = tblEmployees.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(r => r.Fields<String>("EmployeeKey") == TextBox12.Text)
                            .CopyToDataTable();
       // do something with it ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, first off I am very new to programming, so if It doesnt' make perfect sense.  I apologize.  I have been learning this as I go as no where around here offers any C# classes.  I have tried placing that line of code within the textbox12, where it is now and under public employees. All of them give the same error. Doesn't a public class allow for the dataset to be accessible across the entire form or am I misunderstanding this concept?

Comment: @ChrisTurner: Yes you do, an [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) does only control the  accessibility of a member or a type. It does not mean that you cann access members of a public class without an **instance** of it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize the drRow member of myClass this way.  First, the tblEmployees variable is a local variable which goes out of existance when the Employees constructor finishes.  So, it's gone.  But even if it were a class member (defined at class level scope), you still would not be able to use it like you are doing.

Consider getting rid of your myData class and just putting the declaration at the same scope level as your Employees class.

```
public partial class Employees : Form 
{ 
    DataSet[]drRow;
    public Employees() 
    { 
// etc, etc.
```

By the way, this should also fix the TextBox12 context problem.